# javascript - convert localtime to different timezone

Tags: javascript

Does anyone know how to convert "Date().getTime()" to UTC?

Obviously the getTime() is the users local time so I need a function to get the users timezone, convert the timestamp to UTC so I can then * it by -8 to get the current PST time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Date.getTimezoneOffset()`

as seen [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp). It returns the user's browser time relative to GMT, which you'll compare to your server time, relative to GMT.